# Some modifications to the axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the graph of a function and its inverse.  I would like two slight modifications to the axis environment.

I want grid lines drawn at multiples of 5 from the axes.  For some reason, the vertical grid lines are drawn at multiples of 2 from the y-axis. (I also don't want the tick marks labeled on the axes because I am not specifying the functions on the graphs.)  I have `xmin=-12,xmax=17,ymin=-12,ymax=17,`, but the axes are drawn far past these bounds.  It looks awkward.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},clip=false,
    xmin=-12,xmax=17,ymin=-12,ymax=17,
    axis lines=middle,
    restrict x to domain=-12:17,restrict y to domain=-12:17,
    enlargelimits,
    axis line style={shorten >=-0.1cm,shorten <=-0.1cm,latex-latex},
    %xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    ticklabel style={fill=white},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
    ]

\addplot[dashed,line width=0.2pt,domain=-10:16,latex-latex,name path=reflection_line] {x} node[fill=white, above, right]{$y=x$};
\addplot[domain=-10:16,draw=none,name path=perpendicular_line] {-x + 15};
\addplot[green,domain=-10:4,samples=101,name path=an_exponential_function]  {pow(2,x)} node[fill=white, above, right]{$y=f(x)$};
\addplot[blue,domain=1/2^10:16,samples=101,name path=a_logarithm_function]  {log2(x)} node[fill=white, below=5pt] {$y=f^{-1}(x)$};

%The intersection of reflection_line and perpendicular_line is (5,5). The following commands
%label the point R and mark it with a point.
\coordinate (R) at (7.5,7.5);
\addplot[mark=*,mark size=1.5pt] coordinates {(7.5,7.5)};

\coordinate[name intersections={of=perpendicular_line and an_exponential_function,by={P}}];
\draw[fill,green] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=perpendicular_line and a_logarithm_function,by={Q}}];
\draw[fill,blue] (Q) circle (1.5pt);

%These commands put a brace above line segment PR and label the length `d`.
%First, coordinates for P' and R' are defined to be 2.5pt from PR. A brace is drawn between P'
%and R'. In this way, the label for the length of PR is put in the center of the brace by
%default.
\coordinate (P') at ($(P)!2.5pt!90:(R)$);
\coordinate (R') at ($(R)!2.5pt!-90:(P)$);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt}] (P') -- node[above right=3.5pt and 3.5pt,fill=white, inner sep=1pt]{$\scriptstyle{d}$} (R');

%These commands put a brace above line segment QR and label the length `d`.
%First, coordinates for Q' are defined to be 2.5pt from QR. A brace is drawn between Q'
%and R'. In this way, the label for the length of QR is put in the center of the brace by
%default.
\coordinate (Q') at ($(Q)!2.5pt!-90:(R)$);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,amplitude=5pt}] (Q') -- node[above right=3.5pt and 3.5pt,fill=white, inner sep=1pt]{$\scriptstyle{d}$} (R');
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you have added `enlargelimits` to the options, which extends the axes lines beyond the defined limits, so that behaviour is as you would expect. As you yourself mentioned in a comment, `shorten >=-0.1cm,shorten <=-0.1cm` in `axis line style` also helps extend the axis lines.

To remove all ticklabels, just add `xticklabels={},yticklabels={}`. Your example gives me ticks every 5 units on both axes as it is, but if you want to specify this explicitly, just add `xtick={-10,-5,...,15},ytick={-10,-5,...,15}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},clip=false,
    xmin=-12,xmax=17,ymin=-12,ymax=17,
    axis lines=middle,
    restrict x to domain=-12:17,restrict y to domain=-12:17,
    xticklabels={},yticklabels={},
    xtick={-10,-5,...,15},ytick={-10,-5,...,15},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
    ]

\addplot[dashed,line width=0.2pt,domain=-10:16,latex-latex,name path=reflection_line] {x} node[fill=white, above, right]{$y=x$};
\addplot[domain=-10:16,draw=none,name path=perpendicular_line] {-x + 15};
\addplot[green,domain=-10:4,samples=101,name path=an_exponential_function]  {pow(2,x)} node[fill=white, above, right]{$y=f(x)$};
\addplot[blue,domain=1/2^10:16,samples=101,name path=a_logarithm_function]  {log2(x)} node[fill=white, below=5pt] {$y=f^{-1}(x)$};

%The intersection of reflection_line and perpendicular_line is (5,5). The following commands
%label the point R and mark it with a point.
\coordinate (R) at (7.5,7.5);
\addplot[mark=*,mark size=1.5pt] coordinates {(7.5,7.5)};

\coordinate[name intersections={of=perpendicular_line and an_exponential_function,by={P}}];
\draw[fill,green] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=perpendicular_line and a_logarithm_function,by={Q}}];
\draw[fill,blue] (Q) circle (1.5pt);

%These commands put a brace above line segment PR and label the length `d`.
%First, coordinates for P' and R' are defined to be 2.5pt from PR. A brace is drawn between P'
%and R'. In this way, the label for the length of PR is put in the center of the brace by
%default.
\coordinate (P') at ($(P)!2.5pt!90:(R)$);
\coordinate (R') at ($(R)!2.5pt!-90:(P)$);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt}] (P') -- node[above right=3.5pt and 3.5pt,fill=white, inner sep=1pt]{$\scriptstyle{d}$} (R');

%These commands put a brace above line segment QR and label the length `d`.
%First, coordinates for Q' are defined to be 2.5pt from QR. A brace is drawn between Q'
%and R'. In this way, the label for the length of QR is put in the center of the brace by
%default.
\coordinate (Q') at ($(Q)!2.5pt!-90:(R)$);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,amplitude=5pt}] (Q') -- node[above right=3.5pt and 3.5pt,fill=white, inner sep=1pt]{$\scriptstyle{d}$} (R');
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Without specifying `xtick={-10,-5,...,15}`, the display has vertical lines drawn at multiples of 2 from the y-axis.  Strange.  I don't want the grid lines going as far as the arrow tips on the axes.  How do I shorten the grid lines a bit?  I would like to get the grid lines to be bounded by `xmin=-12,xmax=17,ymin=-12,ymax=17,`.

Comment: I had both `enlargelimits` and `axis line style={shorten >=-0.1cm,shorten <=-0.1cm,latex-latex}`.  I think that using both of them made the unseemly display of the axes.

Comment: @user74973 Ah, yes, didn't notice the `axis line style`, though the effect of that is quite small with your example. I don't really get your first comment though, the grid lines extend as far as the arrow tips (when removing the `shorten` stuff), but that  *is* just to the `xmin`,`xmax`,etc. values you have defined. If you want the axis lines to go beyond the grid, keep the `shorten`.

Comment: Maybe saying "shorten the grid lines a bit" was incorrect.  I want the axes to extend past the grid lines.  I kept the `axis line style={shorten >=-0.25cm,shorten <=-0.25cm,latex-latex}` and removed the `enlargelimits`.  Do both of these specifications extend the axes?  If `enlargelimits` extends the axes, by how much does it extend the axes?

Comment: They do different things. `enlargelimits` (see manual) extends the range of the axis, though I cannot see from the manual how much the default extension is, it will depend on the range of values in the data that is plotted.  The `shorten` commands doesn't alter the range of the axis, it just extends the axis lines by the the given amount. Hence, they don't change what `pgfplots` considers as the axis region.

Comment: When you say "range of the axis," you say that if I specify `xmin=-10` and `xmax=10`, for example, `enlargelimits` will "pretend" that I had something like `xmin=-12` and `xmax=12`.  Is that correct?  If this is what you mean, what does it do to the drawing of the x-axis?  If I have tick marks drawn at unit distances from the y-axis, would four more tick marks be drawn - at `-12`, `-11`, `11`, and `12`?

Comment: @user74973 Yes, something like that. It draws the axis lines and grid further out of course, but if you have specified the ticks manually, you won't get any extra ticks. Don't know what the case is if the ticks are determined automatically.

Comment: I appreciate your time answering my questions.

Comment: I saw on other code the option `enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm}` in an `axis` environment.  Does this extend the axes like `axis line style={shorten >=-0.25cm,shorten <=-0.25cm}` does?

Comment: @user74973 No. Have you read the description in the manual? (All I'm doing is reading the manual and testing things. See https://bitbucket.org/snippets/torbjornt/dEAjR for a quick comparison.)

Comment: I will look and respond to you later.  I am coding for another geometric display now ... and have a question on that.

Comment: @user74973 Better ask a new question I think, this comment-thread is too long as it is.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. any particular reason you choose to use the empty `{}` for `xticklabels` and `yticklabelss` instead of `\empty` for which i think it was intended?

Comment: @aeroNotAuto Didn't think of it. And while I see that it works, `\empty` is in the manual only mentioned/used with `Xtick` and `Xticklabel`, not `Xticklabels` (where `X` is `x`, `y`, `z`).